# Unabled to get rid of BIND 9 chroot

Tags: linux, centos, chroot, bind

I had installed bind-chroot from yum not long ago, and saw that there were errors in the daily logs from named. Under further investigation, I noticed a directory loop. The named files resided under **/var/named**, with the chroot being in **/var/named/chroot**. For whatever reason, **/var/named/chroot/var/named** just leads back to **/var/named**. ls -al doesn't show any link between the directories.

**OS:** CentOS 6.2

**uname -a:**

```
Linux plutonium 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 00:52:02 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64      x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm not really the most linux savvy, so I don't really know what more information I can provide you all with. Please let me know if there is some other piece of information I can give you that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform an `yum remove bind-chroot`, change the directory names and try installing bind-chroot again if the problem continues, remove it again and intall it from an EPEL distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong red hat sets up a series of bindings from non-chroot directories for creating the chroot environment and not having to duplicate everything.

You could check that just executing "mount"  and you'd see the bindings.

If you've detected errors on log files, please paste them in the question so we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If /var/named/chroot/var/named is a symlink to /var/named, then remove the symlink, then move /var/named/ to /var/named/chroot/var/named and create a symlink for /var/named to /var/named/chroot/var/named. In this way, named is chrooted and the symlink leads to the chroot jail.

Or you could remove bind-chroot, make sure any directories for named are removed and re-install bind-chroot to confirm whether package is at fault here, or that something just went wrong when you installed it the first time.

Of course, backup any of your config files to a separate directory so you can refer back to them when you re-install.